# The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)

Tags: java

I am getting the error *The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)*

Here is the code

```
} else if (Integer.parseInt(answerField.getText() == null)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not enter an answer!");
                }
```

I have also tried this but it doesn't work:

```
(Integer.parseInt(answerField.getText().equals("")))
```

&

```
(Integer.parseInt(answerField.getText().length()) == 0)
```

I just want to check to see if nothing has been entered and if so display a JOptionPane.

Edit: The var answerField is a JTextField, where the user inputs an answer of a mathematical question. So the ActionListener then determines if the answer is correct, hence the parseInt (because of it being a mathematical operation)

```
do {
        checkButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(answerField.getText()) == correctAnswer) {
                    count++;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct");

                } else if (Integer.parseInt(answerField.getText().length()) == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not enter an answer!");
                } else {
                    count++;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
    } while (count < 11);
```

Comment: You're passing a boolean expression to parseInt(), that expects a String. Don't try to do everything in a single line. Check if the string is empty/null, then parse it (if it needs to be parsed). But given what you're saying, all you need is `if (answerField.getText().isEmpty())`

Comment: * Why do you want to use Integer.parseInt() ??
In order to check if there is text you need to use this
`if  (answerField.getText()  == null || answerField.getText().equals(""))

Comment: Note that if answerField is a JTextField or a JTextArea, its getText() method will never return null.

Comment: I'm not well versed with Java, but I know there is a casting syntax to be used when doing type conversion, it may help in your case..

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt(answerField.getText() == null)` is evaluated as
`Integer.parseInt("someTextext" == null)` then

```
Integer.parseInt(true/false)
```

Try to parse a boolean as an Integer will result as an error

To check is your field is null, only do `if(answerField.getText() == null)`

then if is not null you can try to parse the field value to an Integer the way you did.

Answer (score 0):

Lets analise the code you have

```
(Integer.parseInt(answerField.getText() == null))
```

the parameter

```
answerField.getText() == null
```

return a boolean and the method `Integer.parseInt(bool)` is not defined in the Integer class.

It looks like you want to do:

```
else if (someConditionHere) {
      Integer.parseInt(answerField.getText());
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not enter an answer!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all of the values inside of your parse int method return a boolean becuase they are performing a comparison between two values that result in either true or false. You should use Boolean.parseBoolean() to return either "true" or "false" strings

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to call Integer.parseInt, because you already have a boolean expression in your condition:

```
} else if (answerField.getText() == null) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not enter an answer!");
}
```

Note that if conditions in Java can only accept boolean expressions, and you couldn't pass in an integer or whatever else you'd think of as *truthy* or *falsy* (unlike C or Javascript, for example).

Answer (score 0):

If *all* you want to do is check to see if there's some string contained in `answerField`, then all you need to do is check to see if it's not null or empty.

```
if(!("".equals(answerField.getText()) || null == answerField.getText()) {
    // other, non-integer-handling code here
}
```

You do ***not*** want to handle parsing the integer if there's an empty string or if it's `null`, since that could result in a `NullPointerException`.